# What is wrong when I want to get every elements of my list using for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
for i in my_list:
    my_need = my_list (i)
    print (my_need)
```

What's wrong? I want to obtain every elements of my_list using for loop.

Comment: `i` will contain the element not the index of the list which would be accessed with `[]` anyways.

Comment: Indent your code properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A for loop over a list or sequence in python automatically fetches one item at a time from the sequence:

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
for my_need in my_list:
   print my_need
```

or may be you wanted to do something like this:

```
>>> my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
>>> my_need = []
>>> for item in my_list:
...     my_need.append(item)
...     
>>> my_need
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

Comment: i want to make new variable called my_need to represent every elements of my_list

Comment: @lisa just replace `i` with `my_need`, see my updated solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is an array slice:

```
my_need = my_list[:]
```

This will copy each element from my_list into my_need, so then print (my_need) should return

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

If you want to concatenate these into a string, you could also do this:

```
my_need = ""
for i in my_list:
    my_need += i
print(my_need)
```

This time, the print statement will print:

```
abcde
```

Answer (score 0):

Shorter version if you just want a string of my_need:

```
my_need = "".join(my_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up two ways to iterate a list: iterating the list directly, and iterating the indices of the list.

As others have pointed out, the best way to iterate the elements in a list is just this:

```
for my_need in my_list:
    print(my_need)
```

Alternatively, you can iterate the indices of the list, using the `range` and `len` functions. What this does is, it iterates the items in the list created by the `range` function (numbers from `0` to `len(my_list)-1`) and uses those as indices to the actual list:

```
for i in range(len(my_list)):
    my_need = my_list[i] # note: square brackets!
    print(my_need)
```

If you want to iterate both the indices and the items at the same time, a better way to do this is to use the `enumerate` function:

```
for i, my_need in enumerate(my_list):
    print(my_need) # however, index i is not needed in this example
```